# Posting The Following Weeks or Months From an Input Date Selector - HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a date input to output the following weeks or months depending on what has been selected. However, I'm having three issues with this.

Issue 1 SOLVED - I'm trying to set it up with a class to hide the week output if the month is selected and vice-versa; when the submit button is clicked. However, the results just make everything on the page disappears. Not sure why?

Issue 2  - This is more of a method issue than a current error. I'm stuck with the method to get the weeks or the months to print in the ID'd paragraphs corresponding to the entered date.

Issue 3 SOLVED - I'm getting invalid date in my date selector, all I wanted was the current date. So I left it blank but due to the fact that I've changed the way it displays the date being DD/MM/YYYY it's causing this issue.

```js
$("input").on("change", function() {
  this.setAttribute(
    "data-date",
    moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    .format(this.getAttribute("data-date-format"))
  )
}).trigger("change")

function submit() {
  var type = document.getElementById("selectType").value;

  if (type == "Months") {
    document.getElementById("outputMonths").className = "output";
    document.getElementById("outputWeeks").className = "hidden";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("outputMonths").className = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("outputWeeks").className = "output";
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
}

input:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  content: attr(data-date);
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
}

input::-webkit-datetime-edit,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input::-webkit-clear-button {
  display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}

.output {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <lable>Start Date:</lable><br>
      <input type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <br>
      <select id="selectType">
        <option value="Months">Months</option>
        <option value="Weeks">Weeks</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br><input type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="submit()" value="Submit">
    </div>
    <div id="output" class="">
      <h3>Output - 1 Year:</h3>
      <div id="outputMonths" class="output hidden">
        <label>Date 1: </label>
        <p id="dataM1">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 2: </label>
        <p id="dataM2">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 3: </label>
        <p id="dataM3">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 4: </label>
        <p id="dataM4">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 5: </label>
        <p id="dataM5">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 6: </label>
        <p id="dataM6">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 7: </label>
        <p id="dataM7">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 8: </label>
        <p id="dataM8">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 9: </label>
        <p id="dataM9">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 10: </label>
        <p id="dataM10">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 11: </label>
        <p id="dataM11">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 12: </label>
        <p id="dataM12">DD/MM/YYYY</p>
      </div>
      <div id="outputWeeks" class="output hidden">
        <label>Date 1: </label>
        <p id="dataW1">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 2: </label>
        <p id="dataW2">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 3: </label>
        <p id="dataW3">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 4: </label>
        <p id="dataW4">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 5: </label>
        <p id="dataW5">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 6: </label>
        <p id="dataW6">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 7: </label>
        <p id="dataW7">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 8: </label>
        <p id="dataW8">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 9: </label>
        <p id="dataW9">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 10: </label>
        <p id="dataW10">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 11: </label>
        <p id="dataW11">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 12: </label>
        <p id="dataW12">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 13: </label>
        <p id="dataW13">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 14: </label>
        <p id="dataW14">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 15: </label>
        <p id="dataW15">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 16: </label>
        <p id="dataW16">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 17: </label>
        <p id="dataW17">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 18: </label>
        <p id="dataW18">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 19: </label>
        <p id="dataW19">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 20: </label>
        <p id="dataW20">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 21: </label>
        <p id="dataW21">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 22: </label>
        <p id="dataW22">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 23: </label>
        <p id="dataW23">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 24: </label>
        <p id="dataW24">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 25: </label>
        <p id="dataW25">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 26: </label>
        <p id="dataW26">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 27: </label>
        <p id="dataW27">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 28: </label>
        <p id="dataW28">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 29: </label>
        <p id="dataW29">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 30: </label>
        <p id="dataW30">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 31: </label>
        <p id="dataW31">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 32: </label>
        <p id="dataW32">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 33: </label>
        <p id="dataW33">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 34: </label>
        <p id="dataW34">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 35: </label>
        <p id="dataW35">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 36: </label>
        <p id="dataW36">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 37: </label>
        <p id="dataW37">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 38: </label>
        <p id="dataW38">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 39: </label>
        <p id="dataW39">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 40: </label>
        <p id="dataW40">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 41: </label>
        <p id="dataW41">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 42: </label>
        <p id="dataW42">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 43: </label>
        <p id="dataW43">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 44: </label>
        <p id="dataW44">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 45: </label>
        <p id="dataW45">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 46: </label>
        <p id="dataW46">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 47: </label>
        <p id="dataW47">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 48: </label>
        <p id="dataW48">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 49: </label>
        <p id="dataW49">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 50: </label>
        <p id="dataW50">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 51: </label>
        <p id="dataW51">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 52: </label>
        <p id="dataW52">DD/MM/YYYY</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Begin with preventing the form submit: do not bind to button click, but on form submit (since you have the form tag), something like `$('form').on('submit', submit);` than inside `function submit() { .... return false;}` What happens now is: you change couple of classes and submit the form right after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused about what you are trying to achieve. I have fixed the default date value to be set to todays date and I fixed the whole page hiding when you click submit. Please advise on what else you are looking to do:

```js
document.getElementById('datePicker').valueAsDate = new Date();

$("input").on("change", function() {
  this.setAttribute(
    "data-date",
    moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    .format(this.getAttribute("data-date-format"))
  )
}).trigger("change")

function submit() {
  var type = document.getElementById("selectType").value;
    if (type === "Months") {
    document.getElementById("outputMonths").className = "output";
    document.getElementById("outputWeeks").className = "hidden";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("outputMonths").className = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("outputWeeks").className = "output";
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
}

input:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  content: attr(data-date);
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
}

input::-webkit-datetime-edit,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input::-webkit-clear-button {
  display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}

.output {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
    <div>
      <lable>Start Date:</lable><br>
      <input type="date" id="datePicker" data-date="" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <br>
      <select id="selectType">
        <option value="Months">Months</option>
        <option value="Weeks">Weeks</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()">
    </div>
    <div id="output" class="">
      <h3>Output - 1 Year:</h3>
      <div id="outputMonths" class="output hidden">
        <label>Date 1: </label>
        <p id="dataM1">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 2: </label>
        <p id="dataM2">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 3: </label>
        <p id="dataM3">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 4: </label>
        <p id="dataM4">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 5: </label>
        <p id="dataM5">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 6: </label>
        <p id="dataM6">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 7: </label>
        <p id="dataM7">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 8: </label>
        <p id="dataM8">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 9: </label>
        <p id="dataM9">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 10: </label>
        <p id="dataM10">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 11: </label>
        <p id="dataM11">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 12: </label>
        <p id="dataM12">DD/MM/YYYY</p>
      </div>
      <div id="outputWeeks" class="output hidden">
        <label>Date 1: </label>
        <p id="dataW1">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 2: </label>
        <p id="dataW2">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 3: </label>
        <p id="dataW3">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 4: </label>
        <p id="dataW4">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 5: </label>
        <p id="dataW5">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 6: </label>
        <p id="dataW6">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 7: </label>
        <p id="dataW7">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 8: </label>
        <p id="dataW8">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 9: </label>
        <p id="dataW9">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 10: </label>
        <p id="dataW10">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 11: </label>
        <p id="dataW11">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 12: </label>
        <p id="dataW12">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 13: </label>
        <p id="dataW13">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 14: </label>
        <p id="dataW14">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 15: </label>
        <p id="dataW15">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 16: </label>
        <p id="dataW16">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 17: </label>
        <p id="dataW17">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 18: </label>
        <p id="dataW18">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 19: </label>
        <p id="dataW19">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 20: </label>
        <p id="dataW20">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 21: </label>
        <p id="dataW21">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 22: </label>
        <p id="dataW22">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 23: </label>
        <p id="dataW23">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 24: </label>
        <p id="dataW24">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 25: </label>
        <p id="dataW25">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 26: </label>
        <p id="dataW26">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 27: </label>
        <p id="dataW27">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 28: </label>
        <p id="dataW28">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 29: </label>
        <p id="dataW29">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 30: </label>
        <p id="dataW30">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 31: </label>
        <p id="dataW31">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 32: </label>
        <p id="dataW32">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 33: </label>
        <p id="dataW33">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 34: </label>
        <p id="dataW34">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 35: </label>
        <p id="dataW35">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 36: </label>
        <p id="dataW36">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 37: </label>
        <p id="dataW37">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 38: </label>
        <p id="dataW38">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 39: </label>
        <p id="dataW39">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 40: </label>
        <p id="dataW40">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 41: </label>
        <p id="dataW41">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 42: </label>
        <p id="dataW42">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 43: </label>
        <p id="dataW43">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 44: </label>
        <p id="dataW44">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 45: </label>
        <p id="dataW45">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 46: </label>
        <p id="dataW46">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 47: </label>
        <p id="dataW47">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 48: </label>
        <p id="dataW48">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 49: </label>
        <p id="dataW49">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 50: </label>
        <p id="dataW50">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 51: </label>
        <p id="dataW51">DD/MM/YYYY</p>

        <label>Date 52: </label>
        <p id="dataW52">DD/MM/YYYY</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for solving those issues, very helpful. I'll edit the post to mark them as solved. As for the last issue I'm try to get the date that's entered and the post the following 12 months exactly after the set date but only if the selector has selected month otherwise it'll post 52 weeks exactly after the selected date. Does that make sense?

Comment: So if "Months" is selected and let's say today's date is selected (01/06/18) it would then post the following 12 months (01/07/18), (01/08/18) and so on. But if "Weeks" is selected then the following 52 weeks would be posted again using today's date, we'd get (08/06/18), (15/06/18) and so on.

Comment: The reason I'm struggling here, is because it's not just a matter of adding 7 to the day or 1 to the month. Because of course this won't take into account the variation of the days in the months and leap years.

Comment: @MattHutch Have you looked into using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/)? It handles date manipulation very well and it's easy to use.